# Mysql Stored Procedure Search

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Im trying to create a stored procedure that will search the `users` table by matching a first and last name but mine only works when I search just by last name. Can anyone see why

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SearchUserByName`(
IN in_first_name VARCHAR(100),
IN in_last_name VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE in_first_name AND in_last_name = first_name AND last_name;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a really odd where clause you have...

Change it to:

```
WHERE ((in_first_name = '') or (first_name = in_first_name))
AND ((in_last_name = '') or (last_name = in_last_name))
```

If you pass a blank for the first or last name then that part of the clause is ignored.  This allows you to search by first OR last OR both.

Answer (score 0):

To find rows where the last_name column matches the supplied argument value, AND the first_name column matches the supplier argument value...

change the WHERE clause to something like this:

```
  FROM `users`
 WHERE first_name = in_first_name 
   AND last_name  = in_last_name
```